# No sound after upgrade 14.4 to 16.4 on Dell Latitude E5570

Tags: upgrade, sound, dell, pulseaudio

A little more than a week ago, I upgraded Ubuntu from 14.4 to 16.4. Since then, I have not had any sound.

See the [screen shot of my sound settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc0tB.png) to see that the "Play sound through" list box is blank and the output volume slider doesn't work. How might I fix this?

I'm not happy. :(

Inter alia, I found [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS). After following the instructions, I now get an entry "Dummy Output" in the list box, and the output volume slider works. Sadly, still no sound. :(

Found another page (I have a reputation below 10 and hence cannot post more than two links... so I guess you miss out) and completed step 1. Now I've lost entry in the list box and the slider is disabled again. :( Off to bed...

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to let others who have a problem similar to mine that Dell appears to have supplied all drivers for the hardware in the standard installation of 16.4 and later, and hence this problem was (for me at least) easily solved by installing 16.4 as a fresh install from USB. I.e. just do a full install.